# How to remove obsolete account from TFS

Tags: command-line, security, team-foundation-server

I'm the TFS 2012 admin, I use cmd "TFSConfig identities" to found lots of obsoleted accounts, but I get stuck at removing these accounts.

Methods I used :

1. CMD: tfsconfig accounts /delete  account: domain\username
   but get failed message: The accountType option must be specified with this command....
2. Try to remove from project collection's admin page-->security-->users.
   but I cannot see the obsolete uses, it just list the current users.
3. I try to find something from TFS admin console, but did not find a suitable place to do the operation.
4. Google solutions but found nothing.

So could you please provide some guide or any assistant? Thanks.